# how to handle must declare scalare variable exception

Tags: .net, exception

When I run the program .exception "must declare scalare variable @password12"
    through .even I use break point to check value of this parameter variable.it was
     correct.but I am not come toknow where is problem???

```
 code:
         public DataSet showoption1(seter set)
            {


                string sql = "SELECT   menue.menuename,roleid, [right].rightname,
      role.rolename, employee.employeename, employee.password FROM  [right] INNER JOIN 
      permission ON [right].rightid = permission.rightid INNER JOIN  role ON    
     permission.roleid = role.roleid INNER JOIN emp_men INNER JOIN employee ON 

    emp_men.employeeid = employee.employeeid ON role.roleid = employee.roleid INNER JOIN
    menue ON emp_men.menueid = menue.menueid where employee.employeenamee=@username AND    
   employee.password=@password12 ";


                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",set.Username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pasword12",set.Password);
                SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adptr.Fill(ds);
               int id=  Convert.ToInt32( ds.Tables[2].Rows[0]["rooleid"]);

          st.Username=  Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[2].Rows[id]["roolename"]);

                adptr.Dispose();

                return ds;

            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Typo:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pasword12",set.Password);
```

should be

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password12",set.Password);
```

Next job: go and replace the passwords with hashes, salted by account. No really. Storing actual passwords is a really bad idea.

Comment: Sorry,Iam not undestanding your point of view.which password should be replaced??

Comment: @user1405508 If you mean the first bit: add an "s", you just spelt it wrong. If you mean the second bit, then: storing passwords is simply *doing it wrong*. There is very rarely a genuine need to store actual passwords. What you *should* be doing is storing a salted cryptographic hash of the password, and performing the same hash operation on the value the user provides. It is still a simple equality test, but it means that it is impossible to get a list of all the passwords. The "salted" is there to stop rainbow tables from being a viable hash-to-password strategy.